# xdebug.so no suitable image found

Tags: php, homebrew, xdebug, ampps

xdebug.so is not loading.

Output of php -v:

```
Failed loading /usr/local/opt/php71-xdebug/xdebug.so: dlopen(/usr/local/opt/php71-xdebug/xdebug.so, 9): no suitable image found. Did find:
/usr/local/opt/php71-xdebug/xdebug.so: mach-o, but wrong architecture
PHP 7.1.2 (cli) (built: Apr 19 2017 19:17:16) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2017 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.1.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2017 Zend Technologies

macOS version: | 10.12.5
Homebrew version: | Homebrew 1.2.4-107-gaa8eb21
PHP version in use: | 7.1.2
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually this kind of error seems to be fixed by a "reinstall -s".

```
$ brew reinstall -s php71-xdebug
```

Comment: I would be grateful if someone can share a link to where this "s" option for reinstall is documented.